# Syntax error in a Python program

Tags: python, syntax

I am new with python and I am doing challenges to improve. In this challenge I am making a program to ask someone's age and see if they are old enough to vote. I have a syntax error where is highlights the : on the if line and I am unsure on what I have done wrong.

```
name = input("Hello User, welcome to the new voting system, to register please enter your name.")
age = int(input("Thank you " + name + ", please enter your name to continue.")

if age > 18:
   print("Congratulations " + name + " you are old enough to vote")
else:
   print("Sorry " + name + " you are not old enough to vote")
```

Comment: Missing a closing bracket on the previous line.

Comment: Your crowd sourcing Python Linter works fine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
age = int(input("Thank you " + name + ", please enter your name to continue."))
```

needs another bracket

Comment: No problem! I would also suggest that you use a text editor that like sublime that will help you in detecting this kind of common errors. If you are interested in more heavy stuff, learning about an IDE like pycharm is also helpful.

Comment: Also please accept the answer instead of marking solved in the title. It should be a checkbox right next to the answer.